# How do I avoid the "local variable may not have been initialized" Java compilation error? (yes, seriously!)

Tags: java

Before you say that this question has already been answered tons of times, here is my code snippet:

```
final int x;
try {
    x = blah(); 
} catch (MyPanicException e) {
    abandonEverythingAndDie();
}
System.out.println("x is " + x);
```

If invoking `abandonEverythingAndDie()` has the effect of ending the execution of the whole program (say because it invokes `System.exit(int)` ), then `x` is always initialized whenever it is used.

Is there a way in the current Java language to make the compiler happy about variable initialization, by informing it that `abandonEverythingAndDie()` is a method which never returns control to the caller?

I do **not** want to

- remove the `final` keyword
- initialize `x` while declaration,
- nor to put the `println` in the scope of the `try...catch` block.

Comment: just initialize the Variable.

final int x=0;
try {
    x = blah(); 
} catch (MyPanicException e) {
    abandonEverythingAndDie();
}
System.out.println("x is " + x);

Comment: @AndersAnderson `x` is `final`, that's not possible.

Comment: @AndersAnderson have you tried initializing `final` variable twice? Once at point of declaration then inside `try`?

Comment: Jepp, haven't thought about it being final...
Then there is just no option.

Comment: @MadProgrammer No, you will have a "The final local variable x may already have been assigned".

Comment: @brso05 what if an exception doesn't occur? . The OP still wants to print `x`

Comment: @FlorentBayle Good point, temp variable might be the best choice...

Comment: @brso05 - Well. If you don't care, that doesn't mean the OP doesn't. Anyways, check the example I have given in my answer. `x` can be set, but the compiler doesn't seem to see it that way

Comment: What if the OP only wants to initialize the value once (the `final` keyword). What if the value to be initialzied is read from `blah()` and what if `blah()` can thrown an exception. What if the OP wants to print the value of `x` later ? :P

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not without cheating a little by providing a little bit of extra information to the compiler:

```
final int x;
try {
    x = blah();
} catch (MyPanicException e) {
    abandonEverythingAndDie();
    throw new AssertionError("impossible to reach this place"); // or return;
}
System.out.println("x is " + x);
```

You can also make `abandonEverythingAndDie()` return something (only syntactically, it will of course never return), and call `return abandonEverythingAndDie()`:

```
final int x;
try {
    x = blah();
} catch (MyPanicException e) {
    return abandonEverythingAndDie();
}
System.out.println("x is " + x);
```

and the method:

```
private static <T> T abandonEverythingAndDie() {
    System.exit(1);
    throw new AssertionError("impossible to reach this place");
}
```

or even

```
throw abandonEverythingAndDie();
```

with

```
private static AssertionError abandonEverythingAndDie() {
    System.exit(1);
    throw new AssertionError("impossible to reach this place");
}
```

Comment: Or have it 'return' `"OH GOD WHY IS THIS HAPPENING TO ME?!"`.

Comment: This is the best solution until now: It informs the compiler and at the same time cleanly encapsulates it in the abandonEverythingAndDie() method, that can be reused, without polluting the code using it.

Comment: Cheaters never prosper!

Comment: A little comment: my abandonEverythingAndDie() throws a checked exception (it implements a sort of interprocedural `break`) rather than exiting, but the compiler still complains. I will experiment and see if (and what) throwables other than `AssertionError` work. Thank you all again.

Answer (score 4):

No, the compiler only checks that your code is legal. In this context, `abandonEverythingAndDie` is treated as a blackbox and the compiler considers that not all branches cover the initialization of the variable. Even the below code is not accepted by the compiler:

```
final int x;
try {
    x = blah(); 
} catch (MyPanicException e) {
    abandonEverythingAndDie();
    System.exit(-1); // the System.exit() itself is treated as a blackbox :)
}
System.out.println("x is " + x);
```

In other words, the compiler does not "think" about the possible dynamic execution in order to compile the program.

Comment: This... doesn't actually answer the question. It just confirms the problem in the question.

Comment: My answer to OP's question "Is there a way in the current Java language to make the compiler happy about variable initialization, by informing it that abandonEverythingAndDie() is a method which never returns control to the caller?" is no :) Like the other answers mentioned, a `return` or `throw exception` is a workaround for the problem but there is no way to tell the compiler that this specific method effectively ends the program.

Comment: I'm fairly certain the question was _how_ to achieve the effect, not is it possible to do it this _one specific way_.

Answer (score 2):

Surely the simplest, and least hacky approach is just to use a temporary variable...

```
final int x;

int temp;   
try {
    temp = blah(); 
} catch (MyPanicException e) {
    abandonEverythingAndDie();
}
x = temp;
System.out.println("x is " + x);
```

Simple.

Answer (score 1):

Logically, why would you want to do something with `x` if `blah()` had failed? `x` would be uninitialized and this can be dangerous, and so Java prevents this. It's helping you in ways older languages like c would not. So move the `println` inside would be the obvious solution.

```
try {
    final int x = blah(); 
    System.out.println("x is " + x);
} catch (MyPanicException e) {
    abandonEverythingAndDie();
}
```

I think SRP could apply here, depending on your actual code, exception catching is arguably a responsibility, so I might split this one method into two. One that doesn't care about handling, and one that only handles.

```
public void doBlah throws MyPanicException {
    final int x = blah(); 
    System.out.println("x is " + x);
}

public void tryBlahOrDie {
    try{
      doBlah();
    } catch (MyPanicException e) {
        abandonEverythingAndDie();
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not an option, or I would not have asked the question. Please, never answer a question by saying "of course you do not want to do this", because it is quite rude.

Comment: Your question doesn't fully demonstrate the conundrum you are in then.

Comment: @brso05 I said why. Read carefully.

Comment: *"Please, never answer a question by saying "of course you do not want to do this", because it is quite rude."* I didn't write that. I said, what is the reason you would want to `println` on an uninitialised variable? Java is trying to help you by preventing this.

Comment: yes, you did. Saying "why do you want to do this?" and proposing a solution to a different problem is equivalent to saying that the poster is not able to ask a question. I will repeat it **again**, hoping to be able to convey the point. First, the reason is: because I am telling you so. Second, if you publish an answer to my question, answer the question. You can object that I have not been clear about *what* I am asking, and I will clarify, but if you object about *why* I am asking that question and I am not asking a different one that pleases you better, be ready for a downvote.

Comment: I missed your last edit. Unfortunately splitting is not really an option. The code is already split in many strategy objects that implement a set of tasks. I do not want to split the code of a single task in many methods because it would lower readability (the tasks are already very small). Given your good will and work I will upvote you.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if that is an option but you can add

```
throw new RuntimeException()
```

or

```
return;
```

in your catch

```
final int x;
try {
    x = blah(); 
} catch (MyPanicException e) {
    abandonEverythingAndDie();
    throw new RuntimeException(); // here
}
System.out.println("x is " + x);
```

Even if this added `throw` will not be executed because of `abandonEverythingAndDie`, compiler will know that flow of control from this `catch` block can't go back to `System.out.println("x is " + x);` so it will not require initialization of `x`.

Comment: I would rather not doing that. If possible I would like to modify abandonEverythingAndDie() and leave the code that uses it alone.